# How to know the image url is not work in ROku Brightscript

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am getting an image URL from my API. But in some URL it does not work. So, in that case, I want to show a default image.

Anyone know how we can handle this in Roku bright script.
Image url:https://d73o4i22vgk5h.cloudfront.net/13341/public/public/system/posters/188931/standard/MUVI-Cast-400x400-FMBWAC-Season-1--12-_1532288276.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify how you are implementing this. Assuming you are using ***"Poster"*** node to display image. You can track loading of the image using ***"loadStatus"*** field. Also you can specify a default image using ***"failedBitmapUri"*** field. This image will be visible if you poster image failed to load.

Comment: I used this URL https://simultv.com:1400//nodeapi/Channels/file-1591699694712.jpg.It's Working With Google Chrome. But, Not load in Roku. As per your suggestion, I use both fields. here, I getting loadStatus = "failed". But, failedBitmapUri not worked. I also Added SSL Certificate. But, Also not Work. and I already Put my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411763/with-https-url-image-not-load-with-poster-grid.